# Vuejs set a variable maximum for a number input

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have the following vue js script:

```
 <template>
    <div>
        <div v-if='cart.length > 0'>
            <h1>Your Cart</h1>
        <template>
            <fieldset v-for='product in cart'>
                <image :src='product.image'
                <h4>{{product.name}}</h4>
                <input type='number' :max='quantCheck'/>
                <h5>{{product.price}}</h5>
            </fieldset>
        </template>
        </div>
        <div v-else><h1>Your Cart Is Empty</h1></div>
        <br />
        <h5>Subtotal: </h5>
        <h5>Shipping: Free for a limited time!</h5>
        <h2>Total: </h2>
    </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    const apiURL = 'http://localhost:3000';
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                cart: [
                        {
                    id:"56461",
                    name:"lilly",
                    quantity: 2,
                    price: 30.10
                    }, {
                    id:"1253",
                    name:"wild",
                    quantity: 1,
                    price: 31.10
                    }
                    ]
                }
            },
        methods: {
                let quantCheck = this.cart.product.quantity

        }
        }
    </script>
```

I haven't been able to find a good way to make something like this work.

The quantity is variable, and I guess maybe I could make a function that checks the number after each input and pops an error when it goes above but that's not quite the goal.

Anyway sorry if this is a stupid question but thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: If I understand this correctly - you only want shoppers to have the ability to add, lets say, 5 'lilly' products and 10 'wild' products? Will this max quantity remain constant for all products or will each product have it's own max quantity?

Comment: Each product would have had it's own quantity as a prop.  The below answer did work.  Thank you

Answer (score 15):

You can use HTML Form validation for input (type="number"):

```
<input type='number' :max='product.quantity'/>
```

If the input is greater than `max` value then it will show error on Submit the form

Comment: I feel stupid, I would have sworn I tried that but maybe I was doing cart instead of product I don't remember.  Thank you that did work

Comment: not useful since user still can input it directly thru keyboard

Answer (score -2):

I believe that what you want to do is limit the number of items in `<input type='number' :max='quantCheck'/>` based on the `quantity` property of the item in your `cart`. If this is the case, there's a few things that can be improved in your component.

First, you are binding `:max="quantityCheck"` to your input. looking at your component, you have defined `quantityCheck` in the methods option.

```
methods: {
    let quantCheck = this.cart.product.quantity
}
```

**This is incorrect, there's no method declaration.** You'll need to limit the number of characters using the `quantity` property directly:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <fieldset v-for='product in cart'>
        <h4>{{product.name}}</h4>
        <input type='number' :max="product.quantity"/>
        <h5>{{product.price}}</h5>
    </fieldset>
  </div>`,
  data: () => ({
      cart: [
        {
          id: "56461",
          name: "lilly",
          quantity: 2,
          price: 30.10
        },
        {
          id: "1253",
          name: "wild",
          quantity: 1,
          price: 31.10
        }
      ]
    })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

The above works, to test it, enter a value higher than the quantity and the input should highlight on `blur`

If you want better validation, I would suggest using [Vee-Validate](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/) for a simple way to validate your inputs.

Using `VeeValidate`

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
      <div>
        <fieldset v-for='product in cart'>
            <h4>{{product.name}}</h4>
            <input v-validate="'max_value:'+product.quantity" :name="product.name" type="number">
            <span v-if="errors.first(product.name)">Quantity cannot be more than {{product.quantity}}</span>
            <h5>{{product.price}}</h5>
        </fieldset>
      </div>`,
  data: () => ({
    cart: [{
        id: "56461",
        name: "lilly",
        quantity: 2,
        price: 30.10
      },
      {
        id: "1253",
        name: "wild",
        quantity: 1,
        price: 31.10
      }
    ]
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I can enter a quantity >2 and nothing happens, and link is broken to vee-validate